# How can a C# XSLT extension function return an XML fragment that gets used as unescaped XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I've written an XSLT which uses a C# extension function.  That function returns an XML fragment.  Something like this:

```
public string MyFunc(string input)
{
  return "<thisIsXml/>";
}
```

I call it like this:

```
<value-of select="extensions:MyFunc(.)"/>
```

It works, but the response is escaped, so it ends up in the result like this:

```
&lt;thisIsXml&gt;
```

I don't want that -- I want this injected as *actual*, unescaped XML.
Possible?

(This is C#, so XSLT 1.0 only.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, it seems, is to return an XPathNavigator object, rather than a string.  You can form these from fragments.  I wrote this utility function in my extension object:

```
private XPathNavigator GetFragment(string input)
{
  var settings = new XmlReaderSettings()
  {
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
  };

  var doc = new XPathDocument(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(input), settings));
  return doc.CreateNavigator();
}
```

Then I rewrote my extension function to run its string through that function before returning it.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a System.Xml.XmlDocument or System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument in C# and return an `XPathNavigator` from that XmlDocument or XPathDocument. And of course in XSLT you then need `<xsl:copy-of select="extension:MyFunc(.)"/>`.