# How to output raw html with an xsl value-of selector?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, text

I'm modifying an xsl document and I need to add a large chunk of html that is dynamically generated in C#. I figured the easiest thing would be to have my function return a raw HTML string and display that in xsl, but it's displaying as plain text rather than HTML:

```
<xsl:value-of select="bcs:GetProvinceHtml()"/>
```

---

```
    public string GetProvinceHtml()
    {
        var provinces = GetProvinces();
        bool french = Sitecore.Context.Language == Language.DefaultLanguage;
        var html = "<ul>";
        foreach (var prov in provinces)
        {
            var url = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query))
            {
                url = string.Format("{1}?province={0}&lang={2}",
                    prov.Code.ToLower(), HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, french ? "fr-CA" : "en-CA");
            }
            else
            {
                var nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString());

                if (nameValues["province"] != null)
                {
                    nameValues.Set("province", prov.Code.ToLower());
                }
                else
                {
                    nameValues.Add("province", prov.Code.ToLower());
                }

                if (nameValues["lang"] == null)
                {
                    nameValues.Add("lang", french ? "fr-CA" : "en-CA");
                }

                url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
                url = url + "?" + nameValues;
            }

            html += String.Format("<li><a href='{0}'>{1}</a></li>", url,
                !french ? prov.Name : prov.FrenchName);
        }

        html += "</ul>";

        return html;
    }
```

How can I output my HTML string as HTML rather than plain text?

Comment: Your extension function returns the `html` variable, and that is a string. You need to return an `XPathNavigator` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a C# XSLT extension function return an XML fragment that gets used as unescaped XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721749/how-can-a-c-sharp-xslt-extension-function-return-an-xml-fragment-that-gets-used)

Comment: Well, there is `disable-output-escaping="yes"`, but don't blame XSLT if your HTML string generation doesn't pass validation.